# How to make a one script which can scrape any product detail according to the given url

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Idea: user search for the product and that product is searched on multiple Ecommerce website and will scrape that website and show the details in my website, basically what google does when we search for the product

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path='chromedriverpath'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get('website url')
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, features="html.parser")
all_detail=soup.find_all("li", attrs={'class':"product-base"})
title=all_detail[0].find('tag', attrs={'attribute':'title'}) #to find title
price=all_detail[0].find('tag', attrs={'attribute':'price'}) #to find price
link=all_detail[0].find('tag', attrs={'attribute':'title'}) #to find link
```

this code is just to show my approach to find the details and not the actual code

I need a approach on how can I scrape the details of each user search result

Right now I am scraping using tags and their unique attributes but every page has different unique attributes so how can I make a program having this problem

Comment: There's no standard for the HTML structure of e-commerce websites. Unless they use a well-known library like WooCommerce, they're all unique and you need to tailor your scraping code to each of them.

Comment: If i want to scrape only one e-commerce website which has same html structure for every category, then can i scrape different category with same script thought their tags attribute value is different ?@Barmar

Comment: As Barmar said, you can't. You'd have to write separate code to scrape each site and I can guarantee you that it's against their TOS and you'd eventually get banned unless you have some sort of agreement with each site.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible just make sure to check the robot.txt file on the website to ensure it allows web scraping.

```
def link_extraction():
    table = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'tbody')
    Links = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
    Hyper_Links = [link.get_attribute("href")for link in Links]
    return Hyper_Links
```

Multiple different ecommerce websites would need as Barmar mentioned tailored to each one however targeting one isnt an issue as they will use the same default template for most of the website for each product. if you can share the URL then we can have a look and create a script for you.

Comment: https://www.ajio.com/search/?text=tshirt
https://www.ajio.com/s/jeans-3571-88891?query=:relevance&classifier=intent
So these are two links i want to scrape. Html structure is same in both of them